# How to display sql rows until next number is lower than the one before?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is going to be hard to explain properly but i'll try to be clear and I hope someone will understand me and will be able to help.

I have a sql table with something kinda like this:

```
Year Weeks       Trimester Weeks       Unimportant Info
33               1                     bla
34               2                     bla
35               3                     bla
36               4                     bla
37               1                     bla
38               2                     bla
39               1                     bla
40               2                     bla
```

The first 4 trimester weeks is trimester 1, the next 2 weeks are trimester 2 and so on.

The thing I need is that if someone wants to see all the info from, for example, trimester 2 (The year weeks 37 & 38) it shows up.

This would of course be easy if I could just look into the table what year weeks are connected to what trimester weeks, but I don't know any information from the database. I don't know what trimester week is linked to what year week, nothing.

So i think the best solution is to check whether the next row has a number greater than the one before, if so, go on. If not, it's a trimester. Than go on to the next, starting form the 1 (first week) of trimester 2.

To be more clear the result of a user asking for trimester 2 is the following:

```
 Year Weeks       Trimester Weeks       Unimportant Info
    37               1                     bla
    38               2                     bla
```

I couldn't find anyone with a problem similar to this or any explanation. I thought maybe it would be possible with a For Loop but my knowledge isn't unlimited yet and everything I tried didn't work so far.

I'm sorry for this aweful question but you are my only hope left now.

Thanks

Comment: Gosh, it seems like there should be a column with a trimester indicator in it. Can't the database be modified?

Comment: I don't understand it - can't you get the Year Weeks that belong to Trimerster Weeks by specifying Trimerster Weeks in the WHERE clause.

"SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE TrimesterWeeks = 1"?

Comment: You can easily calculate the trimester and the trimester week from the "Year Weeks" column with a simple operation. The "Trimester Weeks" column is useless (redundant).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I can't modify the database sadly enough, i'm not allowed to

Comment: @GratusD. Nope, because I don't know how long each trimester is, and if i ask for 1 i will get week 1 from all the trimesters.

Comment: Ok - I get it now. But aren't trimester length constant?

Comment: @GratusD.  No thats the stupid thing...

Comment: 'and so on' ?? There is no *so* to be *on* here :-(

Comment: Ah, the first 4 `year weeks` is trimester 1!!! Fix your question!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaround by adding the trimester to your table:

```
    SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT CASE WHEN trimester_week = 1 THEN @s:=@s+1 ELSE @s END as trimester,
     your_table.* from your_table, 
     (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
      ORDER BY year_week,trimester_week) as tt
     WHERE trimester = 2;
```

That will show the expected result for any trimester you want. Notice that this solution assumes that trimester week column is an incremental value per trimester and starts ALWAYS with 1.

Comment: Technically, an ORDER BY clause is required here.

Comment: This works great, thank you very much! maybe you can explain how this query works with al the @ signs, or maybe a site which explains it? It looks like magic to me

Comment: @Strawberry  I have no idea though where you want to use an order by clause?

Comment: The @ sign is used to declare a user-defined variable (see more here  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). The variable keeps track of the trimester value and is  initialized with 0 and then increments by one every time the query finds a trimester week with value 1. The ORDER BY was a good advice from @Strawberry to take away the assumption that the records are inserted in sequential order regarding year weeks. I already made the correction.

Answer (score 1):

This may be incomplete - a reflection of the confusion inherent in the question

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.trimester_weeks = x.trimester_weeks 
   AND y.year_weeks <= x.year_weeks 
 GROUP 
    BY x.year_weeks
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```